# Search all tags in an mpd library

Tags: mp3, music, flac, mpd, vorbis

I'm interested in using MPD as my main music playing application, but I really want to be able to search by record label/music publisher ([TPUB](http://id3.org/id3v2.3.0#TPUB) for mp3 or [ORGANIZATION](https://xiph.org/vorbis/doc/v-comment.html) for flac/ogg).

1. does mpd support this kind of behavior (i.e. searching all tags)
2. are there any mpd clients that specifically support doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try `ncmpcpp`, this player has a `Any` (tags) search mode: https://github.com/arybczak/ncmpcpp/blob/f56c825b36d81ca3d49c140f90f7c2ac8f9ce94e/src/search_engine.cpp#L149